How to test validation messages are showing in Blazor website?
I'm writing integration tests using WebDriver against a Blazor Web App. How do I test the visibility of validation messages?
For example, I have the following form:
<form method="post" action="/users/register">
    <div>
        <input id="Name" class="form-control valid" type="text" aria-required="true" />
        <label for="Name" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="Name" class="text-danger"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="EmailAddress" class="form-control valid" aria-required="true" type="email" />
        <label for="EmailAddress" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
    </div>
</form>

And the following test using WebDriver.
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(WebSite.FullUrl(url))

var name = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("Name"))
name.Clear();

var emailAddress = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("EmailAddress"))

At this point I can see the validation message is now visible as expected. How do I programmatically verify that the validation message is visible?

while the validation message is visible, right-click on it and choose, "Inspect".  Copy/paste the relevant markup into your question.

@browsermator Duh! Thank you. Write is as answer and I'll accept it.

I'll let you write the answer for this.  I just hinted at the answer, but I don't know what the answer is.
